# Java file input and output

Tags: java, io, robocode

I have the below method which is meant to append information to a file but I get the error below. In the method I use parts of robocode API which inherits from java.io.InputStream

All the permissions on the files and folders seem fine and the file does exist

```
static public void logInfo(String info) 
{        

    RobocodeFileWriter in;
    try {
        in = new RobocodeFileWriter("log.txt");
        in.append(info);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       


}
```

> SYSTEM: An error occurred during initialization of itc.solomon
>   SYSTEM: java.security.AccessControlException: Preventing itc.solomon from access: (java.io.FilePermission log.txt read): You may only read files in your own root package directory. 
>   java.security.AccessControlException: Preventing itc.solomon from access: (java.io.FilePermission log.txt read): You may only read files in your own root package directory. 
>    at robocode.security.RobocodeSecurityManager.handleSecurityProblem(Unknown Source)
>    at robocode.security.RobocodeSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
>    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:748)
>    at robocode.RobocodeFileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>    at robocode.RobocodeFileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>    at robocode.RobocodeFileWriter.(Unknown Source)
>    at itc.CFile.logInfo(CFile.java:16)
>    at itc.solomon.(solomon.java:43)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
>    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
>    at robocode.peer.proxies.HostingRobotProxy.loadRobotRound(Unknown Source)
>    at robocode.peer.proxies.HostingRobotProxy.run(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this sample:
http://code.google.com/p/robocode/source/browse/robocode/trunk/robocode.samples/src/main/java/sample/SittingDuck.java

I think `getDataFile("log.txt")` will give you proper location.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a bit about this problem. It seems that [there's a bug in the `robocode` package, awkwardly solved by](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Talk:Compressed_Serialization):

```
while (!dataIsLoaded) {
   try {
       tryToReadData;
       dataIsLoaded = true;
   } catch (AnyException e) {}
}
```

It's a quite awful way to solve the problems, for many reasons (ignoring exceptions, busy-waiting, etc.) A more sane way would be downgrading the robocode package to a previous, more stable version.

[See search results here](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&q=java.io.FilePermission++read):+"You+may+only+read+files+in+your+own+root+package+directory"&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=).

Comment: I think the problem above is not the same thing as the thing on wiki. Anyway, wiki is talking about version 1.4.2. Robocode is currently 1.7.2. People learned to report bugs properly since. 
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=37202&atid=419486